# Turing machine accepting mirrored words

Tags: turing-machines

I'm trying to make a Turing machine which accepts $ww^R$, for example $w = aababbabaa$ and I'm unsure as to how to make this work.

Below is an attempt for such Turing machine, but it gets stuck when the second to last b becomes B and the very last a becomes A.

[image: turing machine]

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @nirshahar I added an image of my turing machine from turingmachine.io. I haven't tried to implement the end and control yet.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly the image you gave, it seems like the problem with your TM is that after it reads and convert an `a` to `A`, it searches and converts the rightmost `b` instead of an `a` (same goes when it reads a `b`).

Answer (score 0):

Given,
M(Q,T,B,£,¥,q0,F)
T = Tape Alphabet = (a,b,X,B)
B = blank symbol
¥ = transition function
( To simplify I just wrote imps)
You can see the below link of image right!(reference image)
Click to see the solution.
PS: HOPE YOU LIKED THE ANSWER....
Don't forget to upvote;)[image: reference image]